# How to insert text to scrolledtext while it is in disabled state in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Full Explanation:
I wanted to add a text to **scrolledtext** when user replies in the **entry** box AND I do not want them to change the text inside **scrolledtext**.

In other words: a chat log.

```
myWindow = tk.Tk()
frame_Chat = tk.Frame(myWindow)

#This will be scrolledText
CH = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame_Chat)
CH.grid(row = 1, column =0)

#This will be reply box 
reply = tk.Entry(frame_Chat, bg = "white", width = 70)
reply.grid(row = 6 , column = 0)

def send():
    r = reply.get()
    CH.insert(tk.INSERT, "name: " + r + "\n")

ReplyButton = tk.Button(frame_Chat, text = "Send", command = send)
ReplyButton.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

myWindow.mainloop()
```

I wanted to make the coding as simple as possible by adding a transparent canvas over the **scrolledtext**, so that the user cannot edit anything inside the **scrolledtext**, while allowing it in "enabled" state.

I tried to find this way, but since I'm new to Tkinter... it's probably impossible for me to find the answer...

if the first method is not possible, then suggest another method.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: You can't.  You have to temporarily set the widget's state to "enabled" while inserting text into it, then set it back to "disabled".

Comment: You can use `CH.bind('<Key>', lambda e: 'break')` to ignore all the keys entered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to temporarily set the state to `"normal"`, insert the text, then set the state back to `"disabled"`.

```
CH.configure(state="normal")
CH.insert(tk.INSERT, "name: " + r + "\n")
CH.configure(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

These people don't understand the part where I said I'm a beginner to tkinter and only give hints for the code. I had to search up what they meant and it took me some time to find it.

Just insert CH.config(state = "normal") to switch between disabled and normal state. The lines of code required are seen here

```
def send():
    r = reply.get()
    CH.config(state = "enabled")
    CH.insert(tk.INSERT, "name: " + r + "\n")
    CH.config(state = "disabled)
```

*sigh*